# JavaScript POST to PHP - why does it return null without an If?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This one has really been melting my brain because I'm just not sure why the PHP returns a null set to the front end when it's formatted like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'tempdbconfig.php';

$email=$_POST['email'];

try {
//if($email = "t*****@gmail.com"){
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $sql="SELECT users_id FROM photow_users WHERE email_address = '$email'";

    $result = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $result->execute();

    $data = $result->fetchAll();

    $catValues = array();

    foreach($data as $row) {
        $users_id=$row['users_id'];

        $category_sql="SELECT * FROM photow_categories WHERE users_id = '$users_id'";

        $category_result = $conn->prepare($category_sql);

        $category_result->execute();

        $category_data = $category_result->fetchAll();

        $catValues = array();

        $i = 0;

        foreach($category_data as $category_row) {
            $categories = array();

            $categoryid = $category_row['category_id'];
            $category = $category_row['name'];

            $categories["ID"] = $categoryid;
            $categories["Category"] = $category;

            $catValues[$i]=$categories;
            $i++;       
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($catValues);
//}
//else
//{
//  echo 'no categories';
//}

} catch (PDOException $pe) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}

?>
```

But if I uncomment the if else (the condition is the email that my currently logged in account on the front end is using, so it's akin to me asking if the sky is blue) I get the properly formatted JSON returned to the front end. Am I missing something about PHP or have I made a horrible mistake somewhere?

This is the ajax call in case it's something there that's effecting it - localstorage does contain the correct email address by the way.

```
var email=localStorage.email;

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://w****.azurewebsites.net/getCategoriesjson.php",
        data: 'email='+email,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            var html = '';
            $.each(data, function(index,value){
                html+= '<option value="'+value['ID']+'">'+value['Category']+'</option>';
            }); 
            $('#categories').html(html);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: what's this :- `t*****@gmail.com`? it will never make comparison successfull. change to valid email id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($email = "t*****@gmail.com")
```

this means $email always have the value "t*****@gmail.com",
use == instead

I know u doesnt need this check, this is not what you want,try these changes,
change
`$email=$_POST['email'];` to

```
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
```

And in ajax section

change 
`data:'email='+email` to

```
data:{email:email}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help - I've done both, but the PHP still returns a null set unless I set the $email variable to what I know it's going to be in this instance.

Given the SQL gets what I want when that variable is correct, I can only guess that I'm not passing the email variable correctly from the frontend, or capturing it correctly in the PHP. The data option of the ajax seems to have the correct email address when I debug it too so I'm at a loss

Comment: Var dump $_REQUEST, see network on ajax send, what do you get ???

Comment: May be the database has an entry with t*****@gmail.com, but not the one you send with ajax, are you sending ajax with an email which is in database ???

Answer (score 1):

your if miss a "="

use `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax `data` to

```
data: { email: email },
```

Also change `assignment =` operator to `compare ==` operator

```
if($email == "t*****@gmail.com"){
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
else
{
 echo 'no categories';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must compare values in if block.
Replace this line

```
//if($email = "t*****@gmail.com"){
```

with this

```
//if($email == "t*****@gmail.com"){
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use localStorage.getItem.
2. Also data part of your ajax request should be an object.
3. And make sure to put the ajax request within document.ready

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var email = localStorage.getItem('email');
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://w****.azurewebsites.net/getCategoriesjson.php",
           data: {email: email }, 
           contentType: "application/json",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data){
               var html = '';
               $.each(data, function(index,value){
                   html+= '<option value="'+value['ID']+'">'+value['Category']+'</option>';
               }); 
               $('#categories').html(html);
           }
       }); 
   });
   ```